Масштабирование текста внутри кнопки HTML
Всем доброго времени суток.
И очередной "глупый" вопрос от меня: как задать масштабирование текста внутри кнопки?
Есть у меня такая вот css-структура:
button {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0,2s;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-style: oblique;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lime;
  color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  font-size: 100%;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

Как из нее видно, размер текст по идее должен занимать 100% доступного пространства кнопки, однако на деле, при попытке масштабировать изображение, получается такая вот фигня:

Буду признателен за возможные пути решения данной проблемы и обьяснение почему так вообще происходит?
На сайте нашел похожий вопрос: Размер текста внутри кнопки
Однако ответ, который там дали, не решает проблему, так как нужно, чтобы масштабирование происходило относительно размера кнопки, а не экрана.

С точки зрения user experience масштабирование именно текста внутри кнопки - очень плохая затея, потому что пользователь будет шокирован и неприятно удивлён, когда в одной кнопке будет ОГРОМНЫЙ ТЕКСТ, а в другой маааленький ... и будет размер танцевать на всех кнопках. Это выглядит коряво, некрасиво, неединообразно...Поэтому правильным решением было бы сделать все кнпки одинакового размера и задать им min-width, умещать текст везде одинаково..... Как пример можно взять банально даже stackoverflow: https://i.sstatic.net/Dd7ADzI4.png
